# Tor Browser, Signature verification Failed, Cant check signature: No public key

Tags: linux, verification

I'm trying to install Tor manually on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver using this guide: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tor-browser-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
When I try to verify my signature key it says, No public Key, Checkout the error below

```
gpg --verify tor-browser-linux64-8.0.6_en-US.tar.xz.asc tor-browser-linux64-8.0.6_en-US.tar.xz
gpg: Signature made و 18:27:41 PKT ت 12 فروری 2019
gpg:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is what I get. ubuntu 18 (bionic beaver)/ ZORIN 15---------
Any help is truly appreciated... gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys EB774491D9FF06E2
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Tor Project's [signing keys](https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en) page for more info.

If you followed that tutorial exactly, then you imported a single developer's signing key, but this is not the key used to sign the browser releases.

The output you supplied shows that the actual signing key is `EB774491D9FF06E2`, which shows up on the Tor PGP keys page.

To properly verify, import the correct signing key:

```
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys EB774491D9FF06E2
```

Then you should be able to verify the package's signature using `--verify`.

Answer (score 1):

simply use the below command this helped me

```
curl -s https://openpgpkey.torproject.org/.well-known/openpgpkey/torproject.org/hu/kounek7zrdx745qydx6p59t9mqjpuhdf |gpg --import -
```